# Sending message to content script when on a different domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to send a message to a chrome tab to remove an mutation observer when I navigate off a certain page. However, I get the following error in the dev tools console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Currently I have the below which does work fine when. It will connect and disconnect when the current URL does not match what I want (either on the same domain or difference domain). However, I get the above error when I go to a different domain and navigate.

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "name": "Name...",
    "description": "Description...",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "serviceWorker.js",
        "matches": ["https://*.MY_DOMAIN.com/admin*"],
        "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*.MY_DOMAIN.com/*"],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": ["storage", "scripting", "webNavigation", "tabs"],
    "host_permissions": ["https://*.MY_DOMAIN.com/*"]
}
```

**serviceWorker.js**

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(({ tabId, url: tabUrl }) => {
    if (isSomePage) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: 'addObserver' })
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: 'removeObserver' })
    }
})
```

**contentScript.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(({ action }, _, sendResponse) => {
    const appEl = document.getElementById('app')

    switch (action) {
        case 'addObserver':
            if (appEl) {
                someObserver.observe(appEl, { childList: true, subtree: true })
            }

            break
        case 'removeObserver':
            someObserver.disconnect()

            break
    }

    sendResponse()
})
```

The only solution I have found that fixes the error and keeps all existing functionality is below, however I am not sure on this. My understanding is the below will inject the content script multiple times on the same page potentially and also inject it into pages that are not part of my domain.

**serviceWorker.js**

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(({ tabId }) => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ url: 'https://*.MY_DOMAIN.com/*' }, (tabs) => {
        for (const { id: queryTabId } of tabs) {
            if (queryTabId) {
                chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                    {
                        target: { tabId: queryTabId },
                        files: ['contentScript.js'],
                    },
                    () => {
                        if (isSomePage) {
                            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: 'addObserver' })
                        } else {
                            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: 'removeObserver' })
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Is there an alternative solution to the above problem?

Comment: There's no need for this because when you navigate to a different domain the old page is completely destroyed along with its objects, listeners, and observers. The new page won't even have a content script since its `matches` won't apply so there'll be no onMessage listener either.

Comment: That makes sense when going to a different domain. But what about when going to a different page such as from `domain/dashboard` to `domain/customers`? This is the primary reason I want to remove the observer. It just causes the error when I go to another tab (the tab with my domain still exists) and use that tab (which has a different domain) which I want to try and avoid. Currently I can remove the observer when changing pages within the same domain.

Comment: It depends on the app. The default behavior when navigating between pages, regardless of url, is to start with a new context. Javascript does not survive navigation. The one edge case is simulated navigation via the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). (Some React apps, for example, can make heavy use of this.) Normal navigation isn't actually happening in this case so javascript remains active and is what's handling the appearance of navigation.

Comment: @Ouroborus it is a React SPA. Currently the observers are connected and disconnected in the correct places (when changing pages within the same domain and when going to a new tab and Googling anything). I just get the dev tools error when I switch to a new tab and start Googling something else (not on my domain).

Comment: Which line is flagged for the error?

Comment: @Ouroborus I don't expect it to work on all sites. It currently works as expected with current manifest. I just want to handle the error that shows when not on my domain. The solution I posted that fixes the error also works, however, I don't believe this to be a good fix. I could ignore it and it would still work, however, I would prefer to handle it if I can. The flagged line is just `serviceWorker.js:1`. Alternatively I could not disconnect the observers and I would not get the error, however, I would prefer to try and disconnect them If I could.

Comment: 1) You're sending `removeObserver` but listening to `removeReplace`. 2) You can simply suppress the error by adding `.catch(() => {})` after sendMessage.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh whoops, that was a typo when putting together a small example, I will fix that now in the example. Adding `.catch(() => {})` causes a TS warning of `Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'void'`. It does however suppress the error so thank you for this answer! :). Just to confirm really, but it is safe to suppress this error in my scenario?

Comment: Switch to the official [chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) package.